# Laravel getting last message from chat table

Tags: laravel

I have "chat" table in my db . 
[image]

Where `recipient_user_id` is who getting message and `sender` is sender .
Each message in chat is new row in this table . 
Problem .
When User opens his profile I wanna display

```
 ----------------------------------------------------
|User_name_who_talked_with| last_message| time_sent | 
|----------------------------------------------------
|.....                                              |
|......                                             |
|---------------------------------------------------|
```

My query is

```
$chat = Chat::where('sender_user_id',$user->user_id)
                ->groupBy('recipient_user_id')
                ->orderBy('updated_at','desc')->get();
```

But is displays not last_message . Displays first message .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Chat::where('sender_user_id',$user->user_id)
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    ->get()
    ->unique('recipient_user_id');
```

The query will return all messages ordered by `updated_at` and the `unique` method will reduce it down to one message for each `recipient_user_id`.

```
$chats = Chat::select(DB::raw('*, max(updated_at) as updatedAt'))
    ->where('sender_user_id',$user->user_id)
    ->orderBy('updatedAt', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('recipient_user_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I am not getting the last message. it is giving me first message.

Answer (score 1):

@Dilip answer will also work to fetch unique data but to get latest (unique) messages, use following query:

```
                     $messages = Message::where('receiver_id',$request->user_id)
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                    ->get()
                    ->unique('sender_id')
                    ->values()
                    ->all();
```

Comment: That's almost correct, but the last message only showing if it from senders.

Comment: I mean, i want to get list of users with the last message regardless who is the sender. It could be receiver/sender anyone.